# Draw Ellipse with Java

Tags: java, math, geometry

I have to Create an Image like That:

[image]

in Java.

For this, i have The Method:

```
public Color at(Point point) {

}
```

The Class Color is Predefined, and the Class Point is a Combination
of x- and y-Coordinate of the point. 
The Method "at" is called pixle for pixle.
The Coordinates for Point are from "BORDER_TOP" to "BORDER_BOTTOM"
and from "BORDER_RIGHT" to "BORDER_LEFT" which are at the Start all at 0.5
I Can Draw a circle with Pythagoras and the length of the Vector from the coordinates from "point" when the Borders are all equal. 
But when e.g. the BORDER_TOP and BORDER_BOTTOM are only 0.2 i have to create Ellipses.
And thats when the phytagoras doesnt work anymore.
How do i Create Ellipses?

Comment: Ellipses are defined by equations just like circles are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equations

Comment: Yes, but i have to check, if the point is in the ellipse or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here you can find how to know if your point is in the ellipse or not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse)

Your picture seems to be aligned with cartesian plane, centered, so I would say it is :

```
x^2/rx^2 + y^2/ry^2 ≤ 1
```

means the point is inside the ellipse.